# Change character model for Third Person Shooter game

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm having a little problem.
When you start Unreal engine, you can select the type of your game.
I selected Third Person Shooter game basic stuff..(or something similar). But that's not the problem..
The problem is changing the character model..
I want to have my own character model(no need for animations for now) instead of the base one..
Well, I can put my character into the scene but I can't "stick" my character model with the main camera..
Just something like that..
(I know that this post is not about coding)

Could somebody help me with this please? There must be a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to **create a new pawn** that has the character model you want attached to it. Then, you have to **change the default pawn class** in your world settings so it will spawn when the game starts.

Comment: I can attach a camera to it, but can not attach my model to it.

Comment: Of course you can - add a skeletal mesh component and use the skeletal mesh from your character. If you only have a static mesh then just add a static mesh component.

Comment: I'm spawning under the map.

Comment: Then you have to adjust the spawn transformation accordingly. Have you tried to watch the youtube tutorials? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMsFxzYzFJ8&list=PLZlv_N0_O1gaCL2XjKluO7N2Pmmw9pvhE